Validation Error - cannot read properties of undefined (reading to lower case) in Pactflow
After publishing a consumer contract to Pactflow I receive the following error in the contract comparison tab:
'Validation Error - cannot read properties of undefined (reading to lower case)
The contract causing the issue does not have any undefined properties from what I can tell.
      "description": "A PATCH request to update a card",
      "providerStates": [
        {
          "name": "A card exists with token '987654321'"
        }
      ],
      "request": {
        "body": {
          "address": {
            "addressLine1": "Apt 1A",
            "addressLine2": "123 Madison Ave",
            "addressLine3": "N1 0TS",
            "city": "New York City",
            "country": "USA",
            "county": "Manhattan",
            "postCode": "N1 0TS"
          },
          "fulfilment": {
            "addressLine1": "Apt 1A",
            "addressLine2": "123 Madison Ave",
            "addressLine3": "N1 0TS",
            "city": "New York City",
            "country": "USA",
            "county": "Manhattan",
            "postCode": "N1 2TS"
          },
          "cardholder": {
            "dateOfBirth": "1978-02-02",
            "email": "yuriG@gmail.com",
            "firstName": "Yuri",
            "lastName": "Gargarin",
            "mobile": "07313596365",
            "title": "Dr"
          },
          "customerReference": "newCustomerRef123",
          "designId": "23214",
          "nameOnCard": "Yuri Gargarin",
          "parentCard": "6847819189",
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "method": "PATCH",
        "path": "/api/v1/cards/987654321"
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 204
      }
    }}```


It's likely a problem with your OAS, can you please share that?
